# How to replace the library shared object using PatchELF or chrpath

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

Recently, I want run old application compiled by GCC 3.4.5 on the newest Linux system running GCC 5.2.0.
There is an conflict of the GCC version.
I catch some follow idea:

1. I can rebuild the GCC 3.4.5 on myself specific directory ${MYLIB_DIR}, and compile my application, then deploy it on the GCC 5.2.0 & export LD_LIBRARY_PATH using ${MYLIB_DIR}. But it's wrong because of LD_LIBRARY_PATH will work on the other application, such as shell command: ls, ldd... so this way can't be work.
2. Use command chrpath or patchelf. I can change the runpath of my application, instead of not influence on other applications. But there is some library shared object can't be search in my own directory ${MYLIB_DIR}, such as libcom_err.so, libdl.so.

I'd like to use the second method, the libpthread.so can be searched and replaced exactly, but I want to know how to let GCC search the libcom_err.so in my own ${MYLIB_DIR}?

Comment: I assume you don't have the source to the old program? And is the old program supposed to be used often? If not then why not simply use VirtualBox (or similar) and install an old Linux distribution and run the program for there?

Comment: The environment can't be changed. I have the source code the the old program, but the source cold is too large to finished at time. Fixing old code for GCC 5.2.0 will be run after 1 month. Firstly, I want to use the GCC 3.4.5 library ( include the libcom_err.so... ) on the lastest OS.

Answer (score 0):

Go with approach number 1. I could be wrong here and misinterpreting what you're saying, but it sounds like you're worried other programs completely independent of the program in question will break if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set in the shell they're used from.

If this is the case, you may not be aware that environment variables are only local to their specific subshell. So if you create a subshell, set the variable, then launch your program, other programs from the parent shell will not be affected by that variable.

A common way to do this is to create a bash launcher script, for example `launchProg.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/lib/dir
./myprog
```

where `myprog` is your program located in the same directory as `launchProg.sh`, and `/my/lib/dir` is `${MYLIB_DIR}`.

When you run this script it creates a subshell so the exported variable is not visible outside it.

Comment: My library is the older version. If I use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the other program dependenting on newer version GCC will be error.

Comment: This is the crux of what I'm trying to get to: what is this 'other program'? Is there any reason why it must be run in the same subshell rather than separating subshells as per my description?

Comment: As I said, if you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in subshell as per my description above, other programs in the original shell do *not* see the variable. I'm not saying just set it and run your program, please read my answer again.

Comment: Maybe I can add the library path into the GCC if I recompile the GCC. But I can't find the answer how to add path when GCC reompiled, even use the ./configure --prefix=${MYLIB_DIR}.

Comment: What are you asking? How to compile GCC 3.4.5? Or how to run a program that uses GCC 3.4.5's libraries? I thought it was the latter

Comment: It's sure subshell will run ok. But I found it's failure for some library like as krb5-libs when use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So I want to compile GCC 3.4.5...

Comment: @fengxiaoke : The bug fixed version of gcc-3.4.5 is 3.4.6 ... which is available for the most OS : Slackware,  Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu, etc. .... Please edit your post to include OS name and version.